# String to array with different length using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

String to array with length 2 can be done like below.

```
let str1 = '112213';
let str1Array = str1.match(/.{2}/g);
console.log(str1Array);
```

And the result is

```
[ '11', '22', '13' ]
```

Is it possible to get [ '1', '12', '2' , '13'] similarly?

Comment: It _may_ be possible, depending on the input strings you have and the meaning of array elements. In short: what do you want to match?

Comment: my mistake,  just need to split with different length(here 1 and 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead of `match()` providing both lengths in one regex:

```
(.)(..)?
```

*Optional quantifier is essential when string length is not even.*

JS Code:

```js
console.log(
  '112213'.split(/(.)(..)?/).filter(Boolean)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.clear()
  var re = /(.)(.{2})/g;
  var m;
  var arr = [];
  
  do {
      m = re.exec(text);
      if (m) {
          arr.push(m[1], m[2]);
      }
  } while (m);
  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:myFunction()">
  <input id="input" type="text" value="112213"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```